# How to use "aggregate" chart feature on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Line graphs and most other types in Google Sheets have a checkbox for "aggregate" in the setup tab.  I've tried looking through the instructions but I can't find any documentation on how to use this feature.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  An example data set where it's useful would be really helpful.
I've tried enabling it on various charts with different data, but it never changes anything.

Answer (score 7):

The aggregate feature allows you to aggregate all values that share an identical x-axis key.

Normally, if you have duplicate x-axis keys, your chart will look something like this, with values having the same key forming vertical lines:

[image]

(I've increased the width of the lines to make it easier to see what's happening.)

But perhaps this isn't the behavior you want. Perhaps, instead, you want all y-values with the same x-value to be summed, and only the summation to be plotted. The aggregate feature lets you do this.

First, turn on the aggregate feature, and select the desired aggregation method:

[image]

[image]

After making these edits, instead of y-values with identical x-values resulting in vertical bars, the aggregation of the y-values for a given x-values will be graphed:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if using date or datetime, it disables the proportional plotting over the x-axis.

[image: Aggregate off: datetime proportionally spread across x-axis]

[image: Aggregate on: datetime in series, disrespecting proportionality]

Comment: I guess in this context it is pegging each date to midnight which makes them equispaced

Answer (score 0):

Excel calls this a "category axis", which was how their 2-1/2-D charts worked. It was always (category, x, y), and only x & y acted like numeric ranges. Their 3-D plot is just a tuple of 2-D plots, rather than a 3-D array. I think you're right that the axis gets transformed. Good find.

I also noticed it reformatted my axis to diagonal after adding in lots of labels for all my minor ticks. (I bet major & minor don't mean anything for an aggregate/category axis).